# Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key) with demo project

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I am trying to write some automated tests with the Firebase client sdk. These tests are supposed to use the Firebase Auth Emulator. In order to avoid screwing up production data, I am using the emulators with a demo project id ([as described in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#choose_a_firebase_project)).

I start the emulator with this command:

```
firebase emulators:start --project demo-test --only functions,firestore,storage,auth
```

Then in my tests, I initialize the app with:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth, connectAuthEmulator } from 'firebase/auth'

const app = initializeApp({ projectId: 'demo-test' })
const auth = getAuth(app)
connectAuthEmulator(auth, 'http://localhost:9099')
```

When the test initializes, I get this error:

```
 FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).

    > 45 |     const auth = getAuth(app)
         |                  ^
```

**Note:** This problem only occurs with authentication. I can successfully connect to other emulators like Firestore.

It seems that despite what the documentation says, I can't actually connect the client SDK to a demo project and use the auth emulator. Every time I try, it throws this error.

Does someone know how to set up a demo project emulator and connect the client sdk to the auth emulator?

Comment: did you solve that? i opened a [bug report](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5218) on github for this. hope they fix it.

Answer (score 13):

I put some random value in `initializeApp` and for some reason it worked...

```
initializeApp({
  projectId: 'test',
  appId: 'test',
  apiKey: 'test',
})
```

Comment: i suggest editing the projectId to "demo-test"

Answer (score 0):

I've got this running by using production `apiKey` and `authDomain`.

```js
const app = initializeApp({
  projectId: 'demo-test',
  apiKey: '...',
  authDomain: '...',
});
```

But obviously this isn't ideal considering demo projects shouldn't have any `apiKey` and `authDomain`.

Also, I was worried when the warning "Running in emulator mode. Do not use with production credentials" shows, while I use the production `apiKey`.
But turns out the warning means we shouldn't input any sensitive information (such as real passwords) when running the emulator, as stated [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2773#issuecomment-733930698).
So I think we have no problem for using production `apiKey` to connect to the emulator.